# boot windows installed with UEFI on bios only host

Tags: windows, boot, windows-10, partitioning, bios

I have a crashed computer, the save of my C: partition.
The Windows 10 install was done on a GPT disk with UEFI.
I would like to restart this Windows as a VM on my workstation to get a few things back (not through mounting it in the explorer).
How can I do it? how can I repair Windows so that it boots from only the System partition and without UEFI?

I though about re-creating the system reserved partition alongside my windows partition, use bcdboot to recreate bootfiles and set it as active. But this doesn't work

If you have any ideas.

Comment: Have you considered one of those IDE/SATA to USB adapters as an alternate plan.  It should let you access the files, and is a smaller bar to jump than trying to make a disk boot on a radically different  (virtual) motherboard than it was installed on

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to boot it? Accessing the files directly will be a lot faster and less of a hassle.

Comment: @DanielB yes, there is one, although it's not that important, but I would like to execute a program with it's myriad of specific regexes and back it up propoerly.

Comment: @infixed : I don't have the drive anymore, it's broken. I only have a disk image (cloudberry backup)

Comment: The only way to do this, if the VM does not support UEFI, is to convert the GPT partition into MBR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check that your vm system truly does not support EFI, as it will make this much simpler.

Assuming that it does not, we'll have to convert the disk to MBR labeling, as that's required for BIOS+MBR booting. `diskpart`'s `convert mbr` can do that. Remember to load the windows MBR.

Since we already have a small partition (the ESP) that can hold boot-related stuff, we can use that. Copy bootmgr from an install disk to the root of the ESP, copy BCD from the EFI/BOOT/MICROSOFT directory to the root of the ESP, use bcdedit to designate the new partition to boot windows from. Remember to apply the windows boot sector to the ESP, and mark the partition as active (and possibly set its type back to 0x0c)

Comment: perfect ! it works as well !  as using a windows 10 MBR system reserved and strp it in front of my C: partition, use BCDedit from windows ADK 10, apply bootsect and Boom ! I tested both methods and they work, fantastic !