# How to Restore Windows 10 from EFI system backup to a BIOS only system?

Tags: windows-10, boot, partitioning, bios

I have a backup of my System's partitions that I want to restore to a machine, this destination system doesn't support UEFI mode, in which WIndows 10 was first installed.

My Windows 10 system booted from the EFI system partition, where the BCD datastore is located, how should I convert it to a classical System reserved partition?

I see many documents on how to go from BIOS to EFI, but not any from the reverse procedure.

I unfortunately do not have the possibility to enable UEFI mode on the destination hardware.

I'm trying to restore my Windows 10 machine that I have a backup of the image of on a completely different machine, a KVM based virtual machine to be precise.

I'm not asking on how to change the hardware settings on KVM but how to convert an ESP partition that is restored alongside my C: partition to a standard System served one that could boot on legacy harware presented by KVM to the OS.

The VirtIO drivers are already installed in the OS if this info is needed.

References I've looked at:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/hardware/dn898504(v=vs.85).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/hardware/dn898510(v=vs.85).aspx

And of course my previous question where the answer is unfortunately not working anymore since update 1607 of Windows 10.
[boot windows installed with UEFI on bios only host](https://superuser.com/questions/1062604/boot-windows-installed-with-uefi-on-bios-only-host)

What I tried :

1. Restore only the first partition on a MBR disk
2. Set that partition as active
3. Regenerate boot bcd files with BCD as @snayob explained

   PS C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\amd64\BCDBoot> .\bootsect.exe /nt60 F: /mbr
   Target volumes will be updated with BOOTMGR compatible bootcode.

   F: (\?\Volume{833d781b-d99f-11e6-80ec-8223a3a1c06a})

   ```
   Successfully updated NTFS filesystem bootcode.
   ```

   \??\PhysicalDrive3

   ```
   Successfully updated disk bootcode.
   ```

   Bootcode was successfully updated on all targeted volumes.
   PS C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\amd64\DISM> cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\amd64\BCDBoot"
   .\bcdboot.exe F:\Windows /s F: /v /f BIOS
   BFSVC: ServiceBootFiles MuiOnly:n Res:y Fonts:y BootMgrOvw:nBootStatOvw:n DbgTransports:y CreateSetupObj
   :n
   .\bcdboot.exe : BFSVC Error: Failed to open file F:\Windows\boot\Resources\BOOTRES.DLL for read! Error 
   code = 0x780
   At line:2 char:1

   - .\bcdboot.exe F:\Windows /s F: /v /f BIOS
   - ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

     - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (BFSVC Error: Fa...or code = 0x780:String) [], RemoteExcept 
       ion
     - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

   BFSVC Warning: Failed to determine source OS version.
   BFSVC Error: Failed to open file F:\Windows\boot\PCAT\bootmgr for read! Error code = 0x780
   BFSVC Error: Failed to validate boot manager checksum (F:\Windows\boot\PCAT\bootmgr)! Error code = 0xc1
   Failure when attempting to copy boot files.

Comment: Convert the GPT to MBR, which I suggested, in your other question

Comment: @Ramhound well, in this case it seems to not work anymore from Windows 10 update 1607 and later, hence my question now, have things evolved with  windows bootloader?

Comment: It does indeed work.  I just recently did it.  The Windows Bootloader hasn't changed significantly since Windows XP was released.  The most recent change, but the significant of this change is small, was when Microsoft added support for UEFI.

Comment: unfortunately no, first the diskpart command is refusing to convert the disk : DISKPART> convert mbr

Virtual Disk Service error:
The specified disk is not convertible. CDROMs and DVDs
are examples of disks that are not convertable.

Comment: You can't use DISKPART to do the conversion if you want to keep your data.  You also can't convert to MBR if the system virtual hdd is larger then 3TB (well you can but the largest partition would be under 3TB).

Comment: then what to use? also the disk is only 50GB in total

Comment: Plus when I use Minitool Partition Wizard to convert to MBR without doing anything else then I get greeted by a no boot device foudn error in BIOS https://storage.fr1.cloudwatt.com/v1/AUTH_3bec49d37f1c4de0b883df03bbeb2631/test/2017-01-19_16h49_14.png

Comment: After you convert to MBR you enable Legacy/CPM/Compatabiliy Mode?

Comment: I think that only applicable in the case of UEFI systems, I don't have any CPM/compatibility option on the destination system, I can only boot from a BIOS, thus not providing this functionnality ... if I'm wrong and this setting is located in the OS itself, could you please indicate where I could trigger it?

Comment: If your VM is running Windows 10 and you have a GPT partitions, then the VM supports UEFI, it has to.  The VM bios might not have a way to enable  legacy mode, it would involve, just switching to the BIOS instead of UEFI

Comment: That is exactly my question, how could I modify the Windows disk layout and BCD store to allow for this system to operate on legacy hardware even though it was installed for UEFI. my process that I use for WIndows server 2012 R2, consisting of plugging the C: partition behind a 500mb system reserved small partition created with BCDboot.exe from the Windows ADK worked for Windows 10 until the anniversary update (v1607) hence my questionning about what might have changed

Comment: *Nothing has changed*  Secure Boot is an UEFI only implementation.  Windows isn't configured to use or not use Secure Boot.  If its installed on a GPT partition, then UEFI mode can be enabled, and independant from that fact Secure Boot can be enabled on the system.  If you convert the HDD to MBR then Secure Boot cannot be enabled, because its an UEFI only implementation.

Comment: ok, then what elements should I provide to help solve that solution? would explaining the previous process with commands help?

Comment: @kuzko Not sure if it will work but you can give hybrid MBR a try; i have used it to boot windows installed on gpt disk on legacy pc. https://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 adapts pretty well on hardware change.

For example you can use the same Windows 10 VHD installation on native computer and in Hyper-V.

So you need just to copy your Windows 10 partition - only partition where \windows folder is placed.

1. Make destination disk MBR style, create only one single partition, make partition active, map it to any drive letter say Z: (it will be future c: drive)
2. Copy Windows partition from backup to destination disk (single partition) eventually on file by file basis (depends on software used for making backup).

Then write MBR and PBR using bootsect.exe

3. > bootsect /nt60 Z: /mbr

Then write boot files using bcdboot.exe

4. > bcdboot Z:\windows /s Z:

Comment: Thank you for your time, the bootsect goes successfully but I get a "Failure when attempting to copy boot files." when using the bcdboot command.

Comment: Add option "/f BIOS" at end of bcdboot command given above.

Comment: The same error happens when I run the command "bcdboot E:\windows /s E: /f BIOS"

Comment: You have to execute bcdboot command on elevated admin prompt. How come you don't have read access to F: or E: drive? What OS is on C:, what OS is on F:, what bit-version? You cannot mix bit version of executables. I see you are executing 64bit BCDboot from Windows 10 kit on what OS?

Comment: I use a Windows server 2012 R2 on the C: drive, the resotred OS that I mapped the disk to F: is a Windows 10. Ont the restoring machine (2012) the Windows ADK 10 version 1607 is installed. The restored OS is 64 bit as well as the WS2012R2, my powershell prompt is always elevated and run in ISE.

Comment: Can you browse with File Explorer the files on drive F: (Win10)? Do you get a list of files in F:\Windows\System32 for example. Next would be - can you get the properties of a file in system32 on F: using right click on file?

Comment: Yes I can browser in the F: drive, yes I get a list of files in the Windows/system32 folder of that drive and yes I can read the file properties in that folder.

Comment: Could you try same bcdboot command listed above using it natively - bcdboot executable from the running OS. Maybe there is some binary inconsistency or maybe security is involved? bcdboot has just to copy some files (eventually) and amend BCD.